# Sending data over TCP from arduino to python

Tags: python, tcp, arduino

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now and really just don't know where to go from here.  I've got an arduino uno with a wifi shield connected to a network, and a laptop with Ubuntu connected to the same network.  I'm using the arduino [Wifi Library](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/WiFi) to connect to the network.

I can send data to my laptop from the arduino and print it successfully using: `sudo nc -l 25565`

I am also trying to use the following python code to do the same thing I did with `nc` which is also being run as `sudo` just in case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 25565
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

(conn,addr) = s.accept()
print 'Connection address: ',addr
while True:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print 'received data: ',data
    conn.send('ECHO')
conn.close()
s.close()
```

But it just hangs at `(conn,addr) = s.accept()`.  Using a client python script on the same laptop I can connect to the above server and I can send data to it which the server then prints.

I just have no idea why `nc` will print from the arduino but the python server script won't, even though it will print from a python client.  Could the arduino libraries be failing to follow some standard that python expects?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the arduino libraries are not "*failing to follow some standard*".

Your program is binding to the `localhost` interface, IP address `127.0.0.1`. This means that only programs running on the same PC will be able to connect to your Python server.

Try this:

```
s.bind(('',TCP_PORT))
```

Reference:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html :

> For IPv4 addresses, two special forms are accepted instead of a host address: the empty string represents `INADDR_ANY`, and the string `'<broadcast>'` represents `INADDR_BROADCAST`. The behavior is not available for IPv6 for backward compatibility, therefore, you may want to avoid these if you intend to support IPv6 with your Python programs.

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#creating-a-socket :

> A couple things to notice: we used socket.gethostname() so that the socket would be visible to the outside world. If we had used s.bind(('localhost', 80)) or s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 80)) we would still have a “server” socket, but one that was only visible within the same machine. s.bind(('', 80)) specifies that the socket is reachable by any address the machine happens to have.